# Office 365 Unified API returns only 10 contacts

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using unified graph api v1.0 for office 365 and when i make a query as follow:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts
```

It returns me only **10** contacts.
But when i do:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts/$count
```

I can see that i have **943** contacts

I try to force the api to returns me my 943 contacts by doing:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$top=943
```

But the best i can retrieve is **499** contacts.

Is there any way i can retrieve them all at once, and if not, what would be the way i can paginate them?

My doc reference are: 
http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/query_parameters
and
http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are you getting an `@odata.nextLink` value in your response?

Comment: Ok understood, so nextLink is the way we paginate and the max we can retrieve at once is 499 right ?

Comment: Yes (though I didn't find a discussion on the limit on results in their docs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [$skipToken (Microsoft Graph optional query parameters)](http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/query_parameters) to paginate responses:

> In some response, you'll see an `@odata.nextLink` value. Some of them
>   include a `$skipToken` value. The `$skipToken` value is like a marker that
>   tells the service where to resume for the next set of results. The
>   following is an example of a `@odata.nextLink` value from a response.
>
> ```
> "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$orderby=displayName&$top=3&$skiptoken=X%2783630372100000000000000000000%27"
> ```
>
> For example, to return the next set of users in your organization,
>   limiting the number to 3 at a time in the results, the syntax is as
>   follows.
>
> ```
> GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$orderby=displayName&$top=3&$skiptoken=X%2783630372100000000000000000000%27
> ```

Comment: Agree with BSMP. 
I also suggest looking at the article on paging: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/paging

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i will use this SkipToken option then